# how to increment simple counter using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

i wanted to write simple counter increment code in order to understand redux.
please fix my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/61663y47qn?initialpath=%2F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the problems that you are facing

in `ActionCreator`

you have this code

```
import * as Types from "./Types";

export const incCounter = state => ({
  Type: Types.INC_COUNTER,
  payload: state++
});
```

correct one should be

```
import * as Types from "./Types";

export const incCounter = state => ({
  type: Types.INC_COUNTER,
  payload: state
});
```

`Type` should be `type` and you don't need to increment state here, that is supposed to happen in reducer.

---

in `counterReducer` you have

```
export const counterReducer = (state = counterInitialState, action) => {
  switch (action.Type) {
    case Types.INC_COUNTER:
      return { ...state, state: action.payload++ };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

correct code should be

```
export const counterReducer = (state = counterInitialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Types.INC_COUNTER:
      return {...state, counter: ++action.payload};
    default:
      return {...state};
  }
};
```

Again, `Type` should be `type` and increment should happen before you assign the state, `action.payload++` is wrong, it should be `++action.payload`

---

in `index.js`

you have this

```
const mapDispatchToProps = state => ({
  updateCounter: () => incCounter(state)
});
```

which should be

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  updateCounter: state => dispatch(incCounter(state))
});
```

Lastly, you have

```
<button onClick={incCounter(props.currentCounter)}>Update counter</button>
```

which should be

```
<button onClick={props.updateCounter.bind(null, props.currentCounter)}>Update counter</button>
```

You don't want to execute the function, you want to pass the function as a click handler and if you want to pass some argument to it, you can bind it using `bind` function. Just be careful about the first argument passed to bind => it is execution context not the first argument of the function, your argument goes second.

Working code can be found here. https://codesandbox.io/s/8nyjxvp2k9

Comment: Thank you Sir for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version:

[image: Edit redux counter]

There were quite a few different little problems, so you'll just need to go through file by file to look at the differences.